# 'going on' meaning

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning, usage, adverbs

In some dictionary, I have read this example: "*The amount of homework and other things he had **going on** was stressful.*"

My question is about 'going on', what is it? and what does it mean?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*To go on* is a phrasal verb that means:

- with no object, to be in progress/not done yet, or the same meaning as *to continue*.  It is usually used progressively.  *The party is still going on, we are going on with the project*.

  - *Ongoing* is an adjective form of this phrasal verb.  *The project is ongoing*.
- with an object X, to consider X as evidence for doing something else or as a guide.  *I'm going on what she said, we've got nothing to go on, don't go on just what's in the book.*

It can also still be used non-phrasally:

> I told my sister to go on the stairs for the picture = I told my sister to sit or stand on the stairs.

Informally, *up* can emphasize this non-phrasal meaning:

> I told my sister to go on up the porch and wait for me.

It also can be part of a "bigger" phrasal verb *to go on about X* which means to talk a great deal about X or excessively about X.